# Configure internal PID minter in Fedora Commons 6

Tags: repository, fedora-commons

How can I configure the internal PID minter of repository Fedora Commons 6 so that it generates unique IDs by combining a string and a sequential number?

I couldn't find the configuration file as in previous versions of Fedora Commons.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.